# How to know why event bridge invoke failed?

Tags: aws-event-bridge

I have a lambda function. It's deployed by serverless. So a rule always be created in my custom event bus automatically. After I send a test event to my bus. This rule can be triggered. But is always invoke fail. I try to find the reason but nothing can be saw beside invoke metrics.

Strangely, if I manually create a rule for the same. This manually created rule can always fire and successfully invoke the lambda function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer it myself. I solved it.

AWS eventbridge has no logging. However, by configuring the dead letter queue to reduce the number of retries and the holding time of the unprocessed state, events that cannot be successfully called by the target service can be entered into the dead letter queue as soon as possible.

Then, we can see the error code and error message in the attributes of the message.

Comment: Hey, I'm facing this problem now and I've seen your proposed solution in other places but my problem is I can't see the option to add a dead letter queue. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @John, this is in "advanced" od "additional" something like this. It's at the end of the page when you create target for a rule.